# Using Go template with YAML

Tags: go, yaml, go-templates

My Go application provides an API which is doing health checks by contacting other internal APIs for the host passed in the request.

For example the API endpoint will be `/api/v1/host/my-host-01`. In YAML configuration file app users will be specifying what healthchecks they want to be executed, it should support dynamic variables. For example config.yaml.go:

```
healthchecks:
  hostIsAvailableInAnotherAPI:
    httpGet:
      path: /another-api/{{.Hostname}}
```

So before reading the YAML config I would render it with as a Go template on each GET request to my API with `.Hostname` and only then run the health checks and provide result.

Is that a good approach to use Go template + YAML or is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - it sounds like you want to write data to a file just so you can read it from that file from the same process, which seems really inefficient when you already have the data in memory.

Comment: The file on disk would be config.yaml.go created/edited manually. My app would read it once, parse it as a go template and then parse again as YAML. My question is if that's a good way of providing a configuration for an application which requires dynamic variables or I should use something like HCL from hashicorp. Does it make sense now?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very good way to do that at all, but there's basically no information given in the question as to what you're actually trying to accomplish, so it's hard to give a better recommendation.